# How to reload a class imported from a module in python console?

Tags: python, class, import, module

The way I imported it:

```py
from my_package.my_module import My_Class
```

Here, `my_package` is a subdirectory in my current project with an empty `__init__.py` in it.

Then I edited `My_Class` and wanted to reload it without restarting the python console. How do I do this?

None of `importlib.reload(My_Class)`,  `importlib.reload(my_package.my_module)` or `importlib.reload(my_module)` works because `My_Class` is not a module and I didn't import a module.

Edit:
Since two comments mentioned this: I tried re-importing using the same command. Didn't work - sill the "old" class gets imported. I even tried deleting the module at all, still no problem re-importing in the same python console.

Comment: Have you tried reimporting it?

Comment: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):
"If a module imports objects from another module using `from … import …`, calling `reload()` for the other module does not redefine the objects imported from it -one way around this is to re-execute the from statement, another is to use import and qualified names (module.name) instead.

If a module instantiates instances of a class, reloading the module that defines the class does not affect the method definitions of the instances — they continue to use the old class definition. The same is true for derived classes."

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I tried and it is still importing the "old" content. I even went as far as delete the module and there is no problem reimporting.

Comment: @matszwecja I tried reimporting obviously; didn't work. See updated post.